# Empty string in List causes incorrect index to appear in the ModelState keys

Tags: c#, .net, json, list, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller that expects `List<int>`
and to demonstrate the strange behavior I write out all the ModelState errors and I write out all the values

```
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(List<int> MyInts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Errors: ");
        foreach(string Error in this.ModelState.Keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Error);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Values:");
        foreach(int MyInt in MyInts)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(MyInt.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I post:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I get

```
Errors: 
Values:
1
2
3
4
```

makes perfect sense.

next I post

```
[1, 2, 3.5, 4]
```

I get:

```
Errors: 
MyInts[2]
Values:
1
2
4
```

makes perfect sense too

When I post

```
[1, "", 3, 4]
```

I get

```
Errors: 
MyInts[2]
Values:
1
3
4
```

what is going on here? MyInts[2] is perfectly fine and I can even see it come through in the Values. I need this data to be correct so I can tell my user which field they need to fix.

There's also a problem if I post:

```
[1.1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I get

```
Errors: 
MyInts[0]
MyInts
Values:
```

So if the first value is invalid the whole list gets declared invalid and I'm left with an empty list. Again, I need the error to tell what went wrong, I don't know what's going on here.

I came across this behavior with nullable DateTimes and it's essentially the same issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've found something that doesn't work as you need, and that can't be changed, so you need to implement an alternative solution.

I recommend you to read about [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). In this artcile, and the list of links at its end, you get an explanation of how binding works, and, specially how you can customize the binding process.

There is another simpler way, but that should be implemented in all the methods that have this problem: parse yourself the Request, and correct the Model State. You can do this in an static method so that it can be reused anywhere you get find this problem.

If you want to know why this is happening, you can download the source code and debug it. You can find info on [ASP.NET web stack](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) and [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest) at Codeplex.

Comment: The whole point of having the data type returned as an argument in the controller is to avoid DTOs - if I parse the response myself it introduces a whole new theoretically unnecessary layer to the process. I mean hey, why not accept a string in the Post method and send a stringified json object? It is my opinion that this behavior is Microsoft's fault, they are supposed to be offering accurate error reporting via the ModelState.

Comment: If you're looking for a solution to your problem because there is something that doesn't work, I've pointed you to several different solutions: your own "manual" parsing in case of errors, a customized binder for arrays that works as expected, or debugging the source code, and, ideally, creating an issue in the project, or even offering a solution. Apart from this, if you want we can discuss about whose the fault is and so on, but I think that it's pointless, and no matter how much we discuss it, unfortunately it will not solve the problem.